# How to get place where image from photo gallery was taken (not GPS coordinates) on iOS?

Tags: ios

Images in Photos app on iOS sometimes have associated place where photo was taken. E.g., city name or even particular place in the city like Pike Place Market in Seattle. This place is displayed as image title in nav bar in iOS Photos app.

How can I get that metadata?

I'm accessing photos using `PHAssetCollection.FetchAssetCollections` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get location directly from `PHAsset` Object. To get place Info. i.e Address use `CoreLocation` Framework

```
func reverseGeoCoding(asset: PHAsset) {
    let location = asset.location

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("Geo Coding Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let placemarks = placemarks,
            let firstPlacemark = placemarks.first,
            let addressDictionary = firstPlacemark.addressDictionary else { return }
        //            let street = addressDictionary["Street"]
        //            let city = addressDictionary["City"]
        //            let state = addressDictionary["State"]
        //            let zip = addressDictionary["ZIP"]
        print(addressDictionary.description)
        if let array = addressDictionary["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [Any] {
            let address = array.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ",\n")
            print("Address : \(address)")
        }   
    }
}
```

## Update:

For the address you can get address directly from `CLPlacemark` Object

See the reference : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark

from previous code `let firstPlacemark = placemarks.first`

`firstPlacemark.property` (property mention below)

```
// CLPlacemark properties

open var name: String? { get } // eg. Apple Inc.

open var thoroughfare: String? { get } // street name, eg. Infinite Loop

open var subThoroughfare: String? { get } // eg. 1

open var locality: String? { get } // city, eg. Cupertino

open var subLocality: String? { get } // neighborhood, common name, eg. Mission District

open var administrativeArea: String? { get } // state, eg. CA

open var subAdministrativeArea: String? { get } // county, eg. Santa Clara

open var postalCode: String? { get } // zip code, eg. 95014

open var isoCountryCode: String? { get } // eg. US

open var country: String? { get } // eg. United States

open var inlandWater: String? { get } // eg. Lake Tahoe

open var ocean: String? { get } // eg. Pacific Ocean

open var areasOfInterest: [String]? { get } // eg. Golden Gate Park
```